# What are the standard dimensions for fridges in the US?

Tags: refrigerator, kitchen-counters

I just want to know whatever I can about the (seemingly) existing efforts to standardize fridge sizes.

I found this question ([Refrigerator enclosure dimensions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5084/refrigerator-enclosure-dimensions)), but I'm looking more for a list of logical potential sizes.

I also found [this link to "thor kitchen"](https://thorkitchen.com/whats-the-standard-refrigerator-size/):

> ....the standard size for a professional-grade refrigerator falls between 30 to 36 inches width, 67 to 70 inches in height, and 29 to 35 inches in depth.
>
> ....some smaller kitchens may consider a smaller size refrigerator to be more standard. In fact, it is very common to find smaller refrigerators in places such as condos and rental apartments. These smaller sizes, however, are not the standard size.

So this is a basic range for the width and depth of normal medium-sized fridges, but the article does not yield a very technical or professional understanding.

I'd like to know from someone who deals with this a lot: what dimensions do you snap between when you design a kitchen around a fridge?  And are there standard sizes for smaller fridges?

I don't want to choose a fridge size that is non-standard and hard to replace in the future.

Comment: A standard fridge is about the same as an average person...

Comment: The door bins should be wide enough for gallon milk jugs.

Answer (score 4):

There appears to be no real standards.  I found this website which has a table with dimensions:  http://www.rempros.com/dimensions/refrigerator_sizes.html

But the best thing I found is just Home Depots search filters.  From the images below you can deduce some things.  There are a total of 1,161 items, these are the percentages each dimension make up of that total.

**Common Widths:**

- 22 in - 3.6%
- 24 in - 11.6%
- 28 in - 10.1%
- 30 in - 9.9%
- 33 in - 12%
- 36 in - 30.8%

**Common Depths (tolerance up to +1.5 inches):**

- 22 in - 4.7%
- 24 in - 10%
- 26 in - 9.7%
- 28 in - 15.6%
- 30 in - 20%
- 32 in - 23.4%
- 34 in - 8.1%

[image]
[image]